Create a countdown using AMP for Email
Did anyone have a success with building a countdown using AMP for Email?
In the AMP documentation I've found this component. Unfortunately it cannot be used in AMP for Email:

This was confirmed by trying to use it in AMP Playground (it rendered the email as invalid).
Any ideas?
Thanks

I don't think it's possible today.
As you mentioned, amp-date-countdown is not allowed in the email format. Without such component, I don't think it's feasible to achieve a constantly-refreshing countdown in AMP for Email. AMP in general forbids visible changes to the document that are not a result of a user gesture, unless it's a done by  a vetted component like amp-date-countdown which has been designed to not cause any page jumps, layout shifts or any other jankiness.
